# Issue With Mysqli Prepared Statement When Using AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a simple insert into MySQL.  I am using mysqli using prepared statements.  Below is the code:

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE $table SET $name = AES_ENCRYPT(?,'$key') WHERE $id_name = '$_SESSION[$id_name]'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_query);
$stmt->bind_param('b', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

Yes, I am declaring $mysqli with a connection to the mySQL database server earlier in the code.  $key is also declared earlier in the script.  Below is the output into the mySQL general log file when this code is invoked:

```
120104 10:46:18   359 Connect   root@localhost on payday-loan-leads
                  359 Query     SELECT table_location, id_name, encrypt FROM insert_information WHERE required_field_name = 'first_name'
                  359 Prepare   UPDATE personal_info SET first_name = AES_ENCRYPT(?,'^&IK8uBo92X04jhAHPUH(Y(8p3)&^ndlkj32') WHERE personal_id = '5282'
                  359 Execute   UPDATE personal_info SET first_name = AES_ENCRYPT('','^&IK8uBo92X04jhAHPUH(Y(8p3)&^ndlkj32') WHERE personal_id = '5282'
                  359 Close stmt
                  359 Quit
```

As you can see, mySQL is preparing the INSERT query but does not capture the value of $value.  When I remove the AES_ENCRYPT from the $sql_query, it works like a charm:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $name = ? WHERE $id_name = '$_SESSION[$id_name]'");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
```

So the problem is with the AES_ENCRYPT function of mySQL. I tried moving the function into the bind_param line and this did not work.  Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `b` (blob) for binding in the aes version, but `s` (string) in the non-aes version. Try `s` in the AES version - it shouldn't matter WHERE a paramter appears in a query, as long as it's not use for a field or table name.